# Passing Array of arrays to controller from Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have some problems. First, i want to store my data to array of arrays collection. and then pass data to controller submit. Here is my code

Ajax.php

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var total = 3;
    var photos = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
     photos[i] = $('#thumbnail'+i+'').children('img').attr('src');
     var collection = {
        'no' : i,
        'photo' : photos[i]
     };

    }

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>create/submit",
        data: {collection : collection},
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
           console.log(response);
           alert('success');
           window.location = '<?php echo base_url()?>create/submit';

        }
    });

});
```

[EDIT]

Controller

```
function submit()

      $collection = $this->input->post('collection');

      print_r($collection);

      if(is_array($collection)) {
          foreach ($collection as $collect) {
           echo $collect['no'];
           echo $collect['photo'];
          }
       }
       else
       {
           echo 'collection is not array!';
       }
}
```

RESULT

```
collection is not array!
```

Based on PeterKa solution, i got this in my console
in Console

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [no] => 0
        [photo] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xap1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/11176494_1106697872689927_2104362222_n.jpg
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [no] => 1
        [photo] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/11376044_838742186174876_410162115_n.jpg
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [no] => 2
        [photo] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/11381470_878168042272606_1132736221_n.jpg
    )

)
```

But, Result in my controller didn't as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `collection` variable is local to the loop and does not hold all the data you iterate through. Instead try something like this, although you don't really need an object to stop the index and `src` -- a plain 1D array would do:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var total = 3;
    var photos = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
         var collection = {
            'no' : i,
            'photo' : $('#thumbnail'+i+'').children('img').attr('src')
        };
        photos.push( collection );
    }
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>create/submit",
        data: {collection : photos},
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
            alert('success');
            window.location = '<?php echo base_url()?>create/submit';
        }
    });
});
```

The data you send is in the form:

```
photos = [
    {
        "no": 1,
        "photo":"this is a link"
    }, 
    {
        "no": 2,
        "photo":"this is a link"
    },
    {
        "no": 3,
        "photo":"this is a link"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks PeterKa! i think it works. But i still have problem to get data from ajax to controller and show it (in controller). what must i do?

Comment: What does `print_r($collection);` in your controller output?

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: my problem now is the result doesn't as expected. Collection doesnt detect as an array

Comment: Looks like a valid array to me. What version of PHP are you on? I tested it [here](http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/is_array.php) and it passes as an array. What happens if you process it with `foreach`?

Comment: i'm just trying to replace photos with another string (not img scr) and it works!. i think, because photo contain URL. but i dont know why. Thanks PeterKa!

Answer (score 4):

You have add `thumbnail` as class for all `<a>`.
Then change the code like this :

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
        var total = 3;
        var photos = new Array();
        $('.thumbnail').each(function (i) {
            photos.push($(this).attr("src"));
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>create/submit",
            data: {'collection': photos},
            cache: false,
            success: function (response)
            {
                console.log(response);
                alert('success');
                window.location = '<?php echo base_url() ?>create/submit';

            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: I did not understand what you are suggesting could you explain a bit more?

Comment: javascript `for`= jquery`each'